# Big Sur keeps asking me to install Command Line Tools

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, big-sur

Ever since I updated to Big Sur (v11.2.3) I am unable to run some tests in Golang that calls /usr/bin/make.
The codebase is: https://github.com/topfreegames/khan/blob/master/cmd/migrate_test.go#L19

Every time the make is called, macOS keeps asking me to install the Command Line Tools, but they are already installed.

Running the make directly from the Terminal works fine.

I've tried removing `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and also `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Also, installing Command Line tools from the Apple website (.dmg) did not work.

Info:

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

```
Xcode 12.5
Build version 12E262
```

pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables

```
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables

version: 12.5.0.0.1.1617976050

volume: /

location: /

install-time: 1619625638

groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but just a thought: since 11.3 was released and, with it. a new version of Xcode, perhaps it is wanting you to upgrade/update macOS?

Comment: I cannot update my mac after 11.2.3, it's my work note, the admin has yet not allowed me to do so. Is there any workaround to make CLDT work?